# Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject coming back as NULL

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm getting back the following string from an API call:

```
{
  "result":
  [
    {
     "sys_id":"12d199028752a9108ae38516dabb35d3"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to deserialize it into this class"

```
  public class result
    {
        public string sys_id { get; set; }
    }
```

I'm using this call: `var x = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<result>(jsonString);`

But "x.sys_id" is always coming up as NULL. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The structure of the JSON response consists of an object which has a property `result` of type `array`, within which you have an object containing a single property `sys_id` of type `string`.

As such, you would need the response to be mapped to something like the following:

```
public class Root // change name as necessary
{
    [JsonProperty("result")]
    public ICollection<ResultItem> Result { get; set; }
}

public class ResultItem // change name as necessary
{
    [JsonProperty("sys_id")]
    public string SysId { get; set; }
}
```

You would then use it as:

```
var x = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(jsonString);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON models an object containing a `result` property containing an array with an object with a `sys_id` property, itself a string. However, your `result` class is for that final object, the one with `sys_id`. You're therefore missing a level: you need something to contain those results.

So let's define a new class:

```
public class Document // or whatever other name you want
{
    public List<result> result { get; set; }
}
```

And then you can deserialize it:

```
var x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Document>(jsonString);
```

Answer (score 1):

sys_id is a string property of an object that is inside of an array, and so the object can be accessed by index only. But you don't need any classes to obtain it.You can just parse a json string

```
string sys_id = (string) JObject.Parse(json)["result"][0]["sys_id"];
```